# Actualizar composer

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, intento hacer arreglos en DomPDF.
Para ello, tengo que hacer una actualización en el Composer, para lo cual debo usar el comando `composer update`, pero me aparece esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parece que hay un error debido a incompatibilidades con DomPDF.
¿Como lo soluciono?

Actualizo. Haciendo un retroceso a una versión anterior logre arreglar parcialmente mi problema.
Pero tras usar de nuevo composer update, aparecio este mensaje de error:

```
Package is not installed: intervention/image-9999999-dev
```

Tengo entendido que lo que ocurre es que composer update es que esta anticuado.

Answer (score 1):

Si tiene `dompdf/dompdf` en su `composer.json` simplemente actualice, especificando `0.8.*` como versión y ejecute

```
composer update dompdf/dompdf
```

despues

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
```

-

La ejecución de un genérico `composer update` afectará a todas las otras dependencias que desee conservar como están actualmente.

Todos los cambios afectados por su `composer update` se graban luego en su archivo `composer.lock`.

Cuando mueva su proyecto a otro lugar o lo desplegará en un servidor, por ejemplo, el `composer install` leerá el archivo `composer.lock` e instalará la versión exacta de sus dependencias que están grabadas en él.

Por lo tanto, estará seguro acerca de la versión de sus dependencias.

Referencia https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48301899/composer-require-gives-errors-while-installing-barryvdh-laravel-dompdf

Comment: Parece que por ahora va bien. Tengo una actualización de mi problema.